# Control column breaking and specify individual column height

Tags: multicol

I have 3 columns of text.

**Column One:**

- Must not flow into other columns

  - I believe this has been solved by `\columnbreak` below
- Need to control text behavior within the column. Currently the text blocks appear to be centering vertically and orienting to the bottom. If you remove the `\lipsum` code in the first column it gets even weirder. Each paragraph should anchor or orient to top.

**Column Two and Three**

- All paragraphs should anchor or orient to top.
- `\section*{Preparation}` should span columns 2 and 3 at the top with a specified column height of 2 inches.
- `\section*{Pointers}` should span columns 2 and 3 at the bottom with either a speficied column height, or with the remainder of space left over after defining the column behavior of `\section*{Preparation}` above.

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}  
\usepackage[top=.5in, right =7mm, bottom=.7in, left=7mm, showframe]{geometry}  
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}  
\usepackage{xfrac}  
\usepackage{multicol}  
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}  
\usepackage{lipsum} % generate filler text

\title{My Recipe}  
\date{}  

\begin{document}  

\maketitle

\begin{multicols*}{3}

\noindent \emph{Makes 4 to 6 Servings}

\begin{tabular}{rl}  
    2 & T Ingredient 1\\  
    \sfrac{1}{2} & t Ingredient 2\\  
    \sfrac{1}{2} & t Ingredient 3\\  
    \sfrac{1}{4} & c Ingredient 4\\  
    \sfrac{1}{4} & c Ingredient 5\\  
    \sfrac{1}{4} & c Ingredient 6\\  
    \sfrac{1}{4} & c Ingredient 7\\  
    2 & c Ingredient 8\\  
    1 & c Ingredient 9\\  
    1 & c Ingredient 10\\  
\end{tabular}

\lipsum[121] % generate filler text  
\columnbreak

\section*{Preparation}
\lipsum[1] % generate filler text  
\columnbreak

\section*{Pointers}
\lipsum[120-121] % generate filler text 

\end{multicols*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I think, a table might be the better approach here

Comment: try https://www.ctan.org/pkg/paracol

Comment: Maybe you are searching [something](https://ctan.org/topic/cooking) like [cuisine](https://ctan.org/pkg/cuisine) or [cooking](https://ctan.org/pkg/cooking).